# Is there a way to know why somebody cast a close vote on my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, vote-to-close

I have posted question that's (in my opinion) very decent, and somebody cast a close vote on it. As I am curious, I would like to know the reason that he selected to request closing my question, and see if I can possibly improve it. Is there a way to discover that?

The question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332053/is-there-a-javascript-gtalk-client-that-i-can-embed-in-my-web-application

Comment: Unless you can read people's minds, no you don't. When you cast a CV, you get to choose from one of 5 reasons. If you have enough rep, you can see how many votes are for which reason. Beyond that, you can only guess.

Comment: That said, your question reads like a recommendation-type question (and potentially a list-type question) which is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Bart Now you are trying to read in my mind. I just asked if it was possible to know the reason selected while voting to close. Now I know it's not possible and that's it. If from that information you think that a feature should be added to SO, it's your request, not mine ;=)

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks, that what I wanted to know.

Comment: Ehm...what now?

Comment: Just to add to @Mysticial comment its normally 3,000 but on your own question its 250 see [What is a “closed” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a post accumulates enough votes to close, it is closed.  Underneath your post a banner is displayed that says that the question was closed, who cast the close votes, and the majority reason for the closing.  The reason is generally a good indicator as to what the voters were thinking when they cast votes.

In your specific case your post was closed for being Off-Topic.  Beyond this general reason, there's no mechanism to get a more concrete reason from the voters as to how exactly your post didn't fit with the guidelines.  You could post a question in the comments section asking why people voted to close, but this is often though of as unwanted noise, and there's no burden of responsibility on the voters to further explain themselves.

You have a few means at your disposal to figure out why your post was closed.

1. Become more familiar with what kinds of questions are and are not tolerated on SO.  This comes with experience
2. Read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'll have more to say on this in a moment.
3. Read Meta.  This gives you a sense for the opinions of the community at large.

In your case, the FAQ spells it out pretty plainly in the section ["What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions

It then lists off several examples of subjective questions that are likely to be closed.  Yours is a prime candidate, asking for what essentially amounts to a list of things similar to the first example given, "What's your favorite ______?"  Questions asking for lists of things are frequently and quickly closed as being off-topic.  I agree with the closure in this case.  You post was off-topic for SO.